# How to center coordinates in nokia here maps using panning?

Tags: here-api

How i can center a coordinates in nokia here maps using panning from my current position to a given lat long..

This is the scenario..

I have a table that the row clickable.

Then when i clicked the row, it will send the data corresponding with the lat long to my javascript function that have a lat long params.

Then plot it to nokia here map in the center, but i like to use panning until the corresponding coordinates centered.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

With HERE API, you can do it like this:

```
GeoCoordinate p = MapFactory.createGeoCoordinate(latitude,longitude);
map.setZoomLevel(map.getMaxZoomLevel()-5);
map.setCenter(p, MapAnimation.BOW);
```

If using Reference library for Google Maps Android API v2, you can do it like this:

```
LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, 10));
```

Comment: if you have a nokiax tag, we would assume you mean the HERE offering for Nokia X platform. and if it is something else, please specify whar it is you are using

Comment: Oh i'm sorry.. its only suggested tag of other website i've research..i'm so new of using nokia here maps to my website i've create now.. thanks

Comment: Ok. No problem. There was nokiax-tag and I replied with that tag in my mind. So this answer is not applicable for your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the web you can use the HERE Maps API for JavaScript.

The method to **re-center** the map is [setCenter(](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Display.html#topic-apiref__Display-setCenter-method)) and uses a similar syntax to the nokia-x syntax:

```
map.setCenter(coord, 'default');
```

**Panning** can be done using the `pan()` method. An example can be found [here](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#panning-the-map).

If you want to use a custom panning technique you'll probably need to use the `geoToPixel()` method to find the displacement of your new center from the old center. (*Hint:*  the old center is always at `map.width/2` , `map.height/2`). You can then start a timer with `setInterval()` and pan a few pixels towards it each time then finally use `clearInterval()` to stop the timer.

Something like:

```
// Assume map center is 200, 100
function panTheMap() {
  var newCenter = map.geoToPixel(coord),
    incX =0, incY =0;
  if (newCenter.x > 200) {
    incX = -1;
  } else if (newCenter.x < 200) {
    incX = 1;
  }

  if (newCenter.y > 100) {
    incY = -1;
  } else if (newCenter.y < 100) {
    incY = 1;
  }

  if (incX == 0 && incY == 0) {
    clearInterval(timerId); // Stop the timer
  } else {
    map.pan(0, 0, incX, incY);
  }
}

var timerId = setInterval(panTheMap, 300);
```